# Convert a string value '21.45E02' to integer in Python

Tags: python

How to convert a string value such as '21.45E02', which has been raised to power to a normal integer?

Answer (score 4):

Convert to a [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#float) first. Which can handle [this format](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#floating). Then if you want an integer use [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#int) to do the conversion, bearing in mind that this will result in a loss of precision which would cause rounding of the number if it did not have a zero fractional part.

```
>>> int(float('21.45E02'))
2145
```